# Process for running test automation against Chrome Beta

Tags: browser-automation, chrome

I've been tasked with determining and implementing a method to run (not yet created) automated tests against the beta version of Chrome (https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/).

We have yet to decide on tooling and scheduling, but even with something in place, I am trying to understand how the process can be automated entirely. Has anyone set something like this up successfully or have recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Before a new major version of Chrome goes to Beta, a matching version of ChromeDriver will be released."](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection)

[image: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home]

It means you can ask for the specific beta target version (currently 75) from your dependency management system and [indicate the location of your Chrome Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729517).